# Sprite Kit Textures Acting Funny

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

OK, this one's got me screaming to the walls... so bear with me please.

I started to code a simple game using the SpriteKit template in Xcode.

I added two PNGs to a folder named `Stage01.atlas` and dragged that to the project. Can't remember if which option I chose, because it appears as a blue folder icon in the project navigator (perhaps because it has an extension?).

Next, I instantiated several sprites using

```
[[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"My_Image_Name_Without_The_@2x_Or_Extension"];
```

At first, it didn't work , because I forgot to enable texture atlases in the build settings. Then, it worked like a charm, but...

Next, I added a third PNG to the atlas to display a new kind of sprite.

The new sprite was nowhere to be seen.

I try a clean install: delete the app from the device, clean, build.

Now all the sprites are rendered as a white quad with  aback border and a big, red "X" inside. I also get console messages along the lines of:

```
SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "My_Image_Name_Without_The_@2x_Or_Extension"
```

I tried removing the .atlas folder and re-adding it, both as *"Create groups for any added folders"* and *"Create folder references for any added folders"* (this can cause a resource to be placed in a subfolder instead of the bundle root, so it usually matters for UIImage etc.), **to no avail**.

I replaced the sprite creation code with this:

```
SKTexture* texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:name];
SKSpriteNode* body = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithTexture:texture];
```

...and placed a breakpoint to see if the texture is `nil`. **It isn't**.

So, what gives?

Side note: The "spaceship" texture bundled with the template renders fine.

Side note 2: Someone create the tag "spritekit" (SO doesn't let me use it 'because it already exists' but it doesn't come up as a suggestion).

Comment: Did you add the third image to the atlas in XCODE or in finder?

Comment: Does it matter? If I add as "folder reference", adding the file in finder makes it appear automatically in Xcode too. Now I'm trying with clean/clean build folder, delete app etc. in several devices and simulators, and the results are spotty...

Comment: It's just a hunch, think I ran into trouble before when I was making changes in xcode, need to test again to be sure

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app from the device/simulator? Also, if you use subfolders in the .atlas folder do **not** use paths. Ie if the image is in "Stage01.atlas/images/image.png" you would still load it as "image" or "image.png" but not "images/image.png".

Comment: I didn't know about subpaths in the atlas, and I can't think of a use for that right now... I mean, what else could you need beyond having your sprites irganized into atlases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use texture atlas textures you first need to load the texture atlas:

```
SKTextureAtlas* atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"Stage01"];
```

Then you can create sprites from its textures:

```
SKTexture* texture = [atlas textureNamed:@"My_Image_..."];
SKSpriteNode* body = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
```

The fact that initially this worked may have been because the images were added without the .atlas generated, and even if you subsequently remove the images from the project they will remain in the deployed app bundle because Xcode doesn't remove resources from an app bundle. So Sprite Kit was using the non-atlas images initially, and not it can't find those and it won't look for them in a texture atlas automatically, nor will it auto-load the atlas.

Comment: I encountered this problem. Turns out the atlas keeps the original name even if it's renamed in the file system or in xamarin. I went back to Photoshop and recreated the file with the right name and it's fine. To test this I viewed the TextureNames array at runtime.

Comment: I've been fine for weeks and I've hit the same problem, added a new png and it got the dimensions, but not the right image. It's as if it cookie-cuttered the dimensions onto existing images. However, when I followed your steps above - all hell broke loose and none of my images work, except the largest ones. I've tried cleaning, deleting derived data and everything. Some images load the 'old way', i've converted every SKSpriteNode call to the above method and even reverting to previous source control is failing to recover. Next step - remove texture atlas and hope!

Comment: No matter what I tried to re add the .atlas folder (renamed it, tried adding it at project and target level), cleaned, rebuilt, only some of my images worked and the majority didn't. I've managed to get up and running again by re-adding the folder without the .atlas extension - and this has allowed me to program, and hopefully things will magically correct themselves when I try and make the app more performant by using texture atlases! (I'm on Version 6.0.1 (6A317))

Comment: When I said 'all hell broke loose' - basically all images took the form of my largest image - but appeared to be cookie-cut images from that large image. Everything was flickering - it wasn't as if I had the red 'X'. This behaviour was on simulators and devices. Do you know if this is a known problem because I can't find any mention of it elsewhere!

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Is this advice current, because -Apple says "Sprite Kit searches first for an image file with the specified filename. If it doesn’t find one, it searches inside any texture atlases built into the app bundle. This means that you don’t have to make any coding changes to support this in your game. " See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html