# Image Naming for iPhone 5 vs iPhone 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have retina images for iPhone 5 and iPhone 4. The only difference is the height of the image, the resolutions are the same.

When I specify the iPhone 4 image, I do myImage@2x.png and for iPhone 5 I do myImageh@2x.png

Then in code

```
if (iPhone_5)
       ... imageNamed:@"myImageh@2x.png"];
else
       ... imageNamed:@"myImage@2x.png"];
```

**The Problem:** This works great on the iOS simulator, however on my actual iPhone 5, the image is enlarged to twice the size. When I do `if (iphone_5) ... imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]` it works fine on real iPhone 5 but simulator complains that it can't find the image file.

What's the right way to do this?

Edit: I forgot to say that my images are in a texture atlas because this is for a spritekit game. Does that change anything?

Comment: I believe you are supposed to use myImage.png (no @2x) in your code.  That has worked for me in the past.  Have you tried changing the size of the iPhone simulator?  Maybe to do a test where you make the @2x solid blue and the other one solid red so you can see which file is being loaded in which scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ever use file extension or "@2x" in `imageNamed:`
Use the name without extension, like @"image".
This way it will load the correct image based on device.

Answer (score 3):

Dont add `@2x` in name. When you access your image using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]`, the correct one will be chosen automatically.

Just try

```
if (iPhone_5)
       ... imageNamed:@"myImageh.png"];
else
       ... imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
```

Comment: If your image extension is png, you may just use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]`

Comment: @RahulPatel my images are also in a Texture Atlas. Does that change anything?

Comment: @Auser Nothing will be changed. Though you are not adding `@2x` but for ratina device, os will load `@2x` images automatically. So everything will be fine

Answer (score 3):

There is no naming convention for compiler to distinguish between iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 images(difference in height only). The `@2x` will only distinguish retina and non-retina images for all iOS device.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just code as `[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]`, no need to add `@2x`. Depending on device and screen size, it will automatically take correct one.

**Note:** You must add both images in bundle(`myImage.png & myImage@2x.png`). Otherwise It won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the new Asset Catalog functionality. Create an image set, then change the device setting from Universal to Device Specific. Check off iPhone and Retina 4 Inch. Then you can add three versions (@1x/@2x and R4) of the image. Then you can just use imageNamed:@"Image" and not have to worry about any checks for screen size etc. The system will do it all for you.

[image: Device Specific]

[image: 3 Versions]

Answer (score 1):

The real problem was that the texture atlas wasn't being loaded properly. See this question for the solution [Sprite Kit Textures Acting Funny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862828/sprite-kit-textures-acting-funny)